# Submitting radio buttons using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble in submitting radio input values using PHP and AJAX. I've constructed the code below, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas? The values of the radio fields need to pass only when the button is pressed

```js
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str == "myvalue") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
      /// location of new code -start
      document.querySelector('input[name="users"]:checked').value;
      /// location of new code -end
        return;
      } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax-php.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

      }
    }

    </script>
```

```html
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="users" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="users" value="2">
      <!-------unable to pass value----------->
      <input type="button" value="myvalue" onclick="showUser(this.value)">

      <!-------unable to pass value----------->
    </form>

    <div id="txtHint">echo results here</div>
```

**ajax-php.php**

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

echo $q;
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: any ideas? it doesnt seem to work thanks

Comment: You have `onclick="showUser(this.value)"` on your `<input type="button">`, but it doesn't have a `value`. You need to get the radio value -> `onclick=showUser(document.getElementByName("users").value)"`

Comment: Thanks would you be able to put it in an example please? I've tried putting the onclick function on the button, but its still not working

Comment: @Mason, Paste your `ajax-php.php` code too. I didn't see any data (radio value) that you are trying to send. You should use `post` method to post radio value.If you want to use `get` method then somehow you should append the value in your url.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'this.value' parameter being passed to your showUser function is scoped to the element with the onclick function. 
So it is trying to send the value of the button element which has no value.

Comment: Thanks @flauntster   :), so how to do pass the values of the radio fields using the button. if the button has value, then it would ignore the values of the radio fields

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine.

```
<input type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
```

The function `showUser` is called by the `button` type input field. And the field has no value.

If you want to send any value then use value `attribute`. For example:

```
<input type="button" value="mayValue" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
```

To access the radio button value you can use this code.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="users"]:checked').value;
```

To send the radio button value follow the code bellow

```
//xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax-php.php?q=" + str, true);
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax-php.php?q=" + document.querySelector('input[name="users"]:checked').value, true);
```

Comment: thanks @Mahbubul Islam I've tired your solution, it almost worked, but the values of the radio fields are not passing, they're passing as 0 only. any ideas? thanks

Comment: You are not trying to get the radio button value.

Comment: Oh right! so would I where would i put the document.queryselector? do I place it inside the button? or make a separate function for it. THANKS

Comment: Put the code where you want to get the value. That can be anywhere in your `showUser` function or other function.

Comment: Hmm, what you've done makes perfect sense. but its still not working. Here is what I did https://jsfiddle.net/z47z15zg/ THanks

Comment: You are trying to get your value in `if(str == "")`. But you have set your value of the button as `myValue`. That's why you are not entering in the condition. You can change the condition to `if(str == "myValue")` then it will work.

Comment: Thanks very much. I changed the statement condition, but its still not passing. I've been trying it for a while now but I cant seem to figure out whats wrong. I appetite all your help but do you think you can take 1 more look please?

Comment: You better update your question with new code and problem

Comment: the code i updated if you could take a look I'd raelly appreciate it thanks

Comment: unfortunately still not working. This is a very difficult problem to solve isnt it

Comment: Make `if (str == "myvalue")` like before `if (str == "")`